# Redirect to user specific URL upon login using database and update this as user progresses

Tags: php, database, redirect

I’m creating a site where users can complete a number of special offers to gain various rewards but I’m struggling how to store the user’s progress.

I envisage if a user completes offer 1 and 2, when they next log in they will be presented with offer 3. You could imagine each offer like a rungs in a ladder, and have to be competed consecutively.

Just to make things clearer; currently, when a user logs in they are redirected to the page for offer 1 which is great. But lets say they leave the site after completing a few offers then later return to the site they will be back to offer 1 again which is not so great. I’m trying to store their progress.

(I think a potential solution) to solve this, I’ve created a column in my database called “redirect” and by default this will be example.com/offer1. I need recall from the database and to redirect to this URL when the user logs in. And, every time an offer is completed this URL is then updated as required so on the next login progress is saved.

So, when the user first logs in they will be sent to the first offer (example.com/offer1) Then , after completing the first offer they will press “proceed to next offer” and this redirect then to offer 2 and will fire a script to update the redirect URL for that user to example.com/offer2 – in this way if they leave the site and return again they will be at offer 2.  After offer 2 is completed and they press “proceed to next offer” , a similar script will fire updating that URL to example.com/offer3 – in this way user progress will be stored.

In a nutshell, I’m asking (1) how can I redirect to a user upon login to the URL in the redirect column and (2) how to update this URL when a button is pressed. Or would there be a more effective way to achieve this (using sessions perhaps).

Below is my current login script which works fine (base.php has the part to connect to the database), currently it directs to example.com/offer1 upon login or if a session is already present and the user hits the log in box. How could I change it to look up the users URL from the redirect column of the database instead? And then how could I code a script to update this URL in the database after each offer is completed?

```
    <?php include "base.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<title>User Management System </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>  
<body>  
<div id="main">
<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))
{
     ?>
    "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com/offer1'" />"


    <ul>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout.</a></li>
    </ul>

    <?php
}
elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
     $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

     $checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
    {
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);
        $email = $row['EmailAddress'];

        $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;

         echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
        echo "<p>We are now redirecting you to the member area.</p>";
        ?>
    "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com/offer1'" />"
<?php       

    }
    else
    {
         echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
    }
}
else
{
    ?>

   <h1>Member Login</h1>

   <p>Thanks for visiting! Please either login below, or <a href="register.php">click here to register</a>.</p>

    <form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
        <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>

   <?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*NB: I'm assuming that the column where the number of the offer is stored is called "offer" and it is in the table named "users".*

## Warnings

- You're using mysql extension for your login code, which is deprecated. Use mysqli instead.
- To hash users' passwords, you're using md5, which can be broken with a brute force attack. Use [crypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) instead.

You can fix these problems using this code for login (obviously, after you have hashed all passwords with crypt() - to do that, see the last point of my answer)

```
    <?php include "base.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<title>User Management System </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>  
<body>  
<div id="main">
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","your_db");
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))
{
     ?>
    "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com/offer1'" />"


    <ul>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout.</a></li>
    </ul>

    <?php
}
elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
     $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

     $checklogin = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($checklogin);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($checklogin) == 1 AND crypt($password, $row['Password']) == $row['Password'])
    {
        $email = $row['EmailAddress'];

        $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;

         echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
        echo "<p>We are now redirecting you to the member area.</p>";
        ?>
    "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com/offer1'" />"
<?php       

    }
    else
    {
         echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
    }
}
else
{
    ?>

   <h1>Member Login</h1>

   <p>Thanks for visiting! Please either login below, or <a href="register.php">click here to register</a>.</p>

    <form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
        <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>

   <?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## Redirecting to the right offer on login

You need to edit this:

```
?>
"<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com/offer1'" />"
<?php
```

In this way:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/offer'.$row['offer'].'\'" />';
```

## Updating the value on button click

1)Create a php file and put into it this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","your_db");
$select = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT offer FROM users      WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'"));
$plus = $select['offer']++;
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET offer=".$plus);
header("location: http://example.com/offer".$plus);
?>
```

2)Point the button to the file you've just created

## Hashing all passwords previously stored with crypt()

Launch this code *once* (**A backup of your database before starting is strongly advised**)

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","your_db");
function Casual($length=22){
    $characters ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
    $code = "";
    for($i = 0; $i<$length; $i++){
        $code = $code.substr($characters,rand(0,strlen($characters)-1),1);
    }
    return $code;
}
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Password,Username FROM users");
while($assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $newcode= '$2a$07$'.Casual(22).'$';
$hashed_password = crypt($assoc['Password'],$newcode);
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET Password='".$hashed_password."' WHERE Username='".$assoc['Username']."'");
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Angelo - so very much appreciated! Enjoy the world cup final if your watching it and have a great evening! :)

Comment: Happy I could help :) Thanks, happy evening to you too :)